# Get values of all textboxes with same name attributes in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get values of all textboxes with same name attributes using jquery.

```
<input type="text" id="text1" name="text[]">
<input type="text" id="text2" name="text[]">
<input type="text" id="text3" name="text[]">
```

How can I get all values of textbox **text[]** and compare it using jquery.

I tried using

```
 var values = $("input[name='text[]']")
 .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
```

but am no successful.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `map` method and store the values into an array.

```
$(function(){
   var values = $('input[name="text[]"]').map(function(){
       return this.value
   }).get()
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UugWW/

Answer (score 2):

This one should work :

```
$('input[name="text[]"]');
```

You can loop on it to get all values.

```
$('input[name="text[]"]').each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's split the requirement into smaller problems.

First you want to select all those inputs.

```
var $inputs = $("input[name='text[]']")
```

It returns a jQuery object, containing all the input named `text[]`.
You also might not need to use square brackets into the name.

```
var inputs = $inputs.get();
```

Extract the matching elements into a plain Array, so that we can now access Array's prototype methods, such as [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
var values = inputs.map(function takeValue(input) {
    return input.value;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a selector like this:

```
$('input[type="text"][name="text[]"')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var textboxcount = document.getElementsByName("text").length;
var textvalue="";
for (var i = 0; i < textboxcount ; i++) {
 textvalue= textvalue + document.getElementsByName("text").item(i).value; 
}
alert(textvalue);
```